How to apply the same tactic to multiple match patterns in Ltac
I'd like to apply the same ltac_expr to multiple match_patterns in the Ltac language.
For instance, I would like to do something like
match goal with
| H : context[true] |- _
| H : context[false] |- _ => my_tactic
end

as in OCaml, which is a syntax error in Ltac.
Thanks!

The documentation you point to does not seem to have such a feature? I are you hoping to use an undocumented hack?

@AndrejBauer I wasn't necessarily hoping to use a hack---I was curious if there was some Ltac-fu practiced by Coq wizards to match against multiple patterns :)

I guess you can just let bind a tactic that you apply in both branches?
